# asignar el valor a una variable en el evento onchange del select

Tags: php, select

bueno mi problema es el siguiente:

ya desde hace un buen tiempo vengo intentando que al modificar un *select*  que aparece en una tabla, este modifique la fila en donde se cambio el select
pero como los datos son mostrados por medio de un *foreach* solamente funciona con el primer elemento pero al cambiar el segundo elemento no hace nada

mi primera pregunta es:

¿que me recomiendan hacer?

y si no hay recomendaciones mi pregunta seria

¿como hago que en el evento onchange del select mande a mandar una funcion y que cuando la llame a mandar envie el valor del select y el de otro campo ?
por ejemplo:

```
<select> onchange"(funcion(valor del select, id))"</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes probar lo siguiente: en el `onchange` con `this.value` le pasas el valor del select y con el `echo` pasas el valor de tu variable php a la función (asumiendo que tienes todo dentro del mismo archivo php)

php:

```
<?php
$otraVariable = 'hello';
?>
```

html (dentro del mismo php):

```
<select name="anyName" onchange="myFunction(this.value, '<?php echo $otraVariable;?>')">
    <option>Selecciona una opción</option>
    <option value="1">Valor 1</option>
    <option value="2">Valor 2</option>
    <option value="3">Valor 3</option>
</select>
```

js:

```
function myFunction(opSelect, otraVar) {
    alert(opSelect + ' ' + otraVar);
}
```

Comment: si me funciona perfectamente, pero para que a la funcion necesito pasar dos valores, el del select y una variable de php , esa variable php la pongo dentro de un input osea que puedo sacarla por medio del input o por medio de la variable php pero como hago que en esa funcion igual pase ese dato?

Comment: mira mi edicion y dime si es lo que buscas mas o menos

Comment: Te recomiendo que compartas más de tú código, así podemos orientarte de mejor manera. quizás lo que propone @andy gibbs te puede servir

Comment: modificado para que le pases el valor de la variable php.. se asume que todo está en el mismo archivo.php y $otraVariable no será modificada por el usuario.. si quieres que pueda ser modificada desde el input prueba la sugerencia del ej. de andy gibbs o de Victor Perdomo

Comment: muchas gracias ya funcionó habia estado batallando con eso , mi codigo quedo igual a como lo pusiste, solo  que en vez del alert ya puse lo que queria que hiciera esa funcion

Comment: excelente! que bueno que te sirvió

Answer (score 2):

mira este ejemplo es muy cencillo

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
       $("#select").on("change",function(){
    var otro=$("#otro").val();   
        var valorSelect=$(this).val()//obtenemos el valor seleccionado en una variable
      console.log( valorSelect+otro)
      })
    
    })
```

```html
<input type="hidden" value="50" id="otro"><!--otro input tipo hidden con un valor-->
    <select name="anyName" id="select">
            <option value="1">Valor 1</option>
            <option value="2">Valor 2</option>
            <option value="3">Valor 3</option>
        </select>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: gracias por la ayuda el problema ya quedo solucionado

Answer (score 0):

No entendí muy bien lo que necesitas, pero así puedes capturar el texto y el valor de un select, y seleccionar otro input y obtener el valor:

```js
function funcion(e) {
  var option = e.options[e.selectedIndex];
  var inputAux = document.getElementById('inputAux');
  alert("Valor Option: " + option.value + ", Texto Option: " + option.text);
  alert("Valor Input: " + inputAux.value);
}
```

```html
<select onchange="funcion(this);">
  <option value="0">Item 1</option>
  <option value="1">Item 2</option>
  <option value="2">Item 3</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="inputAux" value="3">
```

Comment: gracias por la ayuda el problema ya quedo solucionado